# PHPMailer не отправляет письма на кириллический почтовый домен Яндекса

Tags: php, phpmailer

Реализовал отправку данных с форм обратной связи на своем сайте через класс PHPMailer. Зарегистрировал кириллический домен mail.yandex.ru - info@авто-выкуп-по.рф.
Использовал SMTP сервер smtp.gmail.com. 
Вообщем проблема в том что на кириллический домен не приходят сообщения с форм обратной связи отправленных через данную библиотеку, хотя на домены с латиницей все приходит. Помогите пожалуйста! Ниже код!

```html
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
if($_POST){
    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/POP3.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
       //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'auto.vikup2018@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'PXCu5br2';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to*/

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('noreply@example.com', 'Auto-vikup-po.ru');
        $mail->addAddress('info@авто-выкуп-по.рф', 'Order from Auto-vikup-po.ru');     // Add a recipient


        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Order from Auto-vikup-po.ru';
        $mail->Body    = ' <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Order from Auto-vikup-po.ru</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
            
               
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>                        
                                 
                               
                                            
                    </body>
                </html>';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Сообщение отправлено';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Ошибка отправки: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punycode – конвертация.
– это конвертация символов в кодировке Unicode в формат, поддерживаемый инфраструктурой DNS. Алгоритм преобразования описан в стандарте RFC 3492.
Чтобы IDN(Интернационализованные доменные имена)-домен после преобразования нельзя было спутать с обычным доменом, все IDN-домены начинаются со специального префикса «XN--».
Для пользователей Рунета, которые первыми получили возможность регистрации и использования в своих проектах IDN-доменов в кириллической зоне .РФ, Punycode-преобразование применяется не только к имени домена, но и к зоне (домен верхнего уровня – .РФ). Псевдонимом, прописанным в DNS, для домена .РФ является сочетание символов «XN--P1AI». Таким образом, кириллический домен «МойСайт.РФ» после Punycode-преобразования будет выглядеть «XN--80ARBJKTJ.XN--P1AI».

Вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Конвертер: http://idnconv.ru/

Библиотека для (де)кодирования в punycode и обратно: https://github.com/true/php-punycode (давно не обновлялась, не знаю работает или еще)

PHP функция: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-ascii.php

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Возможно ли что SMTP сервер gmail блокирует отправку?

Comment: сомнительно, но можете попробовать использовать другой smtp сервер для тестов, чтобы знать наверняка